# Is it possible to create a notification channel (oreo) with IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT but that will not play any sound?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

Is it possible to create a notification channel (in oreo) with `IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT` but that will not play any sound ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using

```
channel.setSound(null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 2**

channel.setSound(null, null);

**Edit 3**
use IMPORTANCE_LOW its makes no sound

> IMPORTANCE_LOW

added in API level 24
public static final int IMPORTANCE_LOW
Low notification importance: shows everywhere, but is not intrusive.

Constant Value: 2 (0x00000002)

ThAnks you @sdghasemi

**Edit 1**

```
        private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

Read Below

> IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT

added in API level 24
public static final int IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
Default notification importance: shows everywhere, makes noise, but does not visually intrude.

Constant Value: 3 (0x00000003)

> IMPORTANCE_HIGH

added in API level 24
public static final int IMPORTANCE_HIGH
Higher notification importance: shows everywhere, makes noise and peeks. May use full screen intents.

Constant Value: 4 (0x00000004)

> IMPORTANCE_LOW

added in API level 24
public static final int IMPORTANCE_LOW
Low notification importance: shows everywhere, but is not intrusive.

Constant Value: 2 (0x00000002)

> IMPORTANCE_MAX

added in API level 24
public static final int IMPORTANCE_MAX
Unused.

Constant Value: 5 (0x00000005)

> IMPORTANCE_MIN

added in API level 24

public static final int IMPORTANCE_MIN

Min notification importance: only shows in the shade, below the fold. This should not be used with Service.startForeground since a foreground service is supposed to be something the user cares about so it does not make semantic sense to mark its notification as minimum importance. If you do this as of Android version Build.VERSION_CODES.O, the system will show a higher-priority notification about your app running in the background.

Comment: setting it to null is not recommended.. My app force closes on some devices

Comment: @mboy if you dont want to set it to null then use IMPORTANCE_LOW sir